# Override a node page using page manager

Tags: panels, 7, chaos-tool-suite

I know it is possible to override node pages using page manager, then use panels to make new layout by selecting a variant type, and  creating a new variant.

Is it possible not to use the Panels mdoule? I would like to use the Context module, and the default theme regions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. What do you expect Ctools will do for you when you override the node-template, if you are going to use Context? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: You should try display suit module as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to use only context module to override layout.

1. When you first add context @ `admin/structure/context/add`, you need to select `condition` as "path" and reaction can be whatever you want. For ex. choose reaction as "Regions" and then go ahead disable region for the sleected "path" (the one you chose above in condition).

Just remember context module will use your existing theme layout and regions (.tpl.php files) unlike in panels where it allows you create your own regions and layout.